# parse.com android relationship query

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im using Parse.com and I have 2 tables: recipe and ingredient,
now in 1 recipe I have many ingredients
In parse I've connected the table using parent in ingredient table, I'm trying to build an `ArrayList` of Recige (each Recipe contain an ArrayList of ingredients)

Something like this:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Recipe");

        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.include("Ingredient");

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> RecipeList, ParseException e) {

//What should i write here ???
------------------------------

}
```

Thank a lot guys

ingrediant table:
ObjectID ,NAME ,UNIT ,parent

Comment: Do you want to get all the ingredients belonging to a recipe? Or do you want to get all recipes that have an ingredient? Or do you want to get all recipes' ingredients?

Comment: I would like to see how your Ingredient table looks like. I assume you are using a pointer since you are using include. Is the pointed to object containing a list of ingredients, a single ingredient, or something else?

Comment: Hey I Would like to get a list of all recipies - each recipe has list of ingredients (so Iguess the answer is both)

Comment: should I use arrays? How do i do that :)
10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ingredients only belong to a recipe list, I assume that recipies have a reference to the ingredients that belong to their list.

If your reference are pointers to all the ingredients of a recipe then this should suffice

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Recipies");
    query.include("ingredients"); //Name of your ingredients table
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for(int index = 0; index < objects.size(); i++){
                    objects.get(i); //This is a recipe
                    objects.get(i).get("name of the column that hold the pointer"); //This is your ingredient
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("", e.getMessage());
            }
            functionCallback.done(objects, e);
        }

    });
```

More information about 'include' query can be found [here](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide) (under Relational Queries)

If you store the reference in an array you could try and do something like this

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> ingredientQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("ingredients");

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Recipies");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for(int index = 0; index < objects.size(); i++){
                    objects.get(i); //This is a recipe
                    String[] pointers = objects.get(i).get("name of the column that hold the pointer"); 
                    //This is your ingredient reference (if you did 'recipe.put("ingredients", ingredient);', 
                    //the reference that would be saved is the id of the ingredient.
                    ingredientsQuery.whereContainedIn("objectId", pointers);
                    ingredientsQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> ingredients, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for(int index = 0; index < ingredients.size(); i++){
                            ingredients.get(i); //This is a ingredient
                        }
                    } else { 
                        Log.e("", e.getMessage());
                    }
               }
            } else { 
                Log.e("", e.getMessage());
            }
            functionCallback.done(objects, e);
        }

    });
```

Think this should about do it!

Comment: currently I have a pointer to the Recipe in the ingredient.... as for as i know i suppose to put FK in the many side? so no, i do not have ingredient pointer in recipe... maybe this is why im having a problem? thank you so much :)

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I think since you do not have a pointer to an Ingredient object inside your recipe, it isn't able to include ingredients. This is not a problem tho. You just have to retrieve all ingredients that have a pointer to the recipe you want.

Comment: Ya I did what you said and it worked.... but im wondering ... is it efficient?
for each recipe Im looping the whole Ingredient table...

Comment: I wouldn't know if it's efficient or not. All I know is that when you use a pointer to an object, it doesn't compare the entire object, but just the unique objectId. I've been using multi-levelled references (aka person <-> personParty <-> Party) and I havn't had any performance issues. Either calling all persons at a party, or calling all the parties a person goes to.